# check coding style with gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci

I use clang-format to format my source code and I want to verify the coding
style(variable name préfix, indentation, ...) in gitlab CI.

I already use code quality to check variable scop.

I want to add coding style verify in code quality.

someone know how to do that ?

ps: I am not a gitllab CI specialist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this solution, add fallowing lines to `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
format:
  stage: test
  image: nexus.lumiplan.com:8443/toolchain/clang-format:13
  needs: []
  script:
    - find rootToYourProject \( \( -name \*.cpp -o -name \*.h \) -a ! -iname \*soap\* \) -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 clang-format-13 --Werror -n --verbose
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

With this script I do a verification of my clang format configuration to all `.cpp` and `.h` files excepted for soap files.

Comment: Important here is that one uses the `-print0 | xargs -0 -n 1` syntax. You may also see an alternative with `-exec`, but that one will not propagate the return value in case clang-format fails.

Comment: In case you do not want to use this image, you can also get any version of clang-format via PIP, on any image: `pip3 install clang-format==17.0.3`